# Why does Cordova Media Plugin not work in my Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, audio, howler.js, cordova-media-plugin

I'm using Phonegap for my app. I want to use sound in my app. I've used Howlerjs for the sound, but that one doesn't work on Android 4 for some reason. So I decided to try the Cordova Media Plugin, but I can't get that one to work either. I always get error code 1. I've tried to put /android_asset/www/ before the source and I've tried to use .wav files instead of .mp3 files. Everything doesn't work. Hopefully someone can tell me why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you added cordova.js in your index.html ?

Comment: Yes, at the bottom. But I discovered something else... I tested the app only with the Phonegap Dev app but when I really built the app it said it couldn't find Cordova while I do have it on the page

Comment: can you share some of code ?

Comment: `if (device.platform == 'Android') {
              src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            }
            alert(src);
            var mediaRes = new Media(src,
              function onSuccess() {
                  // release the media resource once finished playing
                  alert(1);
                  mediaRes.release();
              },
              function onError(e){
                  console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
                  alert(JSON.stringify(e));
              });
            mediaRes.play();` this is to play the sound

Comment: I'm sorry for the no breaks, Stackoverflow removed them :/

Comment: I got it to work with webaudio. With the use of Crosswalk for Android.